# Can anyone contribute to C++ STL?

Tags: c++, stl

I am using C++ for couple of years and I am wondered how it works. So, I felt interested to see how this project is managed, gone through some google search but found nothing. So, I just want to know that ***`is C++ STL implementation is a open source project`*** like GitHub open source projects or ***`can anyone request for a library that does not exist in c++ but exist in other language`*** or ***`can anyone implement their own version of header and request them for review it?`***

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee those are the ones that "contribute" and "decide" about C++ STL future

Comment: The C++ standard library is really a specification that is part of the C++ standard, and evolved as part of the (numerous) processes of evolving the C++ standard - not as an open source project.  Those processes control how proposals are submitted, reviewed, accepted, evolved, etc.    There are a number of implementations of that specification associated with different compilers - some are commercial (e.g. optimised for use by particular proprietary compilers), some are available under various open source licenses (e.g. the C++ library associated with the gnu compiler colllection).

Comment: Some parts of standard library require/use some compiler intrinsic, and so we cannot have **one** standard library implementation. There is one by compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things here; and I'm not sure which of those you mean.

There is the C++ standard - this is a specification of both the language and the library, and this is developed by the ISO SC22/WG21 committee. See the link that @Berto99 posted above.

Then there are *implementations* of that standard. Compilers and standard library implementations. gcc is one; clang is another, MSVC is a third. There are others (xlc, icc, Embarcadero and so on).

Some implementations are open source, others are not.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Probably if you specify which compiler's STL you interested in, you'll get more specific answer. For example, MSVC STL is here https://github.com/microsoft/STL/ and it is open for contribution.